# Spring Security login page url is not captured by controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just follow some online examples. But somehow /login is not captured by the controller. In my controller I already have the correct mapping. Only thing different is that I have different xmls for security and spring. Will this matter? I have searched a lot online but could not find the answer.

Another question is that I noticed in the user tag there is a authorities attribute but in my case I don't need this attribute. Is it possible to use spring without authorities attribute.

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" login-processing  url="/postlogin" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Do you have the DelegatingFilterProxy set in the web.xml? Is your controller loaded? Any message in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/spring/spring-web.xml
        classpath:/spring/sprint-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

even i had this config I am not sure why spring-web.xml is not loaded. and that is the reason why it is not captured by controller.